# I get the Error "mysqld dead but pid file exists"

Tags: mysql

I get the Error `mysqld dead but pid file exists`

This happens every couple of hours. If I restart it works fine and then goes down again.

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-149 log]# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1 7.8G 1.5G  6.3G   19% /
  devtmpfs 486M  56K  486M    1% /dev
     tmpfs 499M    0  499M    0% /dev/shm
```

`tail` gives:

```
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=4432, /builddir/build/BUILD/ mysql-5.5.38/storage/myisam/mi_delete.c:121 
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] MySQL thread id 4432, OS thread handle 0x7ff640688700, q uery id 269080 localhost root updating DELETE FROM wp_statistics_useronline WHERE timestamp < '1405621693' 
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] Got error 134 when reading table './blog/wp_statistics_u seronline' 
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] Got error 134 when reading table './blog/wp_statistics_u seronline' 
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './blo g/wp_statistics_useronline.MYI'; try to repair it 
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './blo g/wp_statistics_useronline.MYI'; try to repair it 
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=4433, /builddir/build/BUILD/ mysql-5.5.38/storage/myisam/mi_delete.c:121 
140717 18:28:43 [ERROR] MySQL thread id 4433, OS thread handle 0x7ff64074b700, q uery id 269144 localhost root updating DELETE FROM wp_statistics_useronline WHERE timestamp < '1405621693'
```

Comment: You used a utility myisamcheck? <a>http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisamchk.html</a>

Comment: Sounds like something is crashing MySQL. Probably a query that throws a bug. If you manage your own server start out by upgrading your version of MySQL, if you don't try to ascertain which is the query that is causing trouble, find a bug report, and ask your sysadmin(s) or open a ticket asking them to upgrade MySQL because you are experiencing this known bug.

Comment: @RAKK It's a corrupt index.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1371).

It looks like you need to `REPAIR` the table or drop and restore it.